# Entilements not matching provisioning

Tags: iphone, enterprise, ios-provisioning, entitlements

Lately I've been having issues deploying my applications in-house
(enterprise developer program) with reports that some entitlement
values were not the ones specified in the provisioning profile.
I started looking into the issue, and found that, of course, the
values weren't a match:

Contents of the .mobileprovision file:
(as extracted by running `security cms -D -i <mobileprovision file>`)

```
           <key>application-identifier</key>
           <string>M7X5D8MA6U.some.masked.Identifier</string>
           <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
           <array>
                   <string>KNHHJPPHR7.*</string>
           </array>
           <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
           <string>KNHHJPPHR7.*</string>
           <key>get-task-allow</key>
           <false/>
           <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
           <array>
                   <string>M7X5D8MA6U.*</string>
           </array>
```

And the entitlements are (as extracted running: `codesign -d --entitlements - <app bundle>`)

```
   <key>application-identifier</key>
   <string>5R678HMG35.some.masked.Identifier</string>
   <key>get-task-allow</key>
   <false/>
   <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
   <array>
           <string>5R678HMG35.some.masked.Identifier</string>
   </array>
```

I'm not specifying any entitlements file in my project, and the
mobileprovision file was downloaded fresh from the Portal.

Should I create an Entitlements.plist with those values just to make
the installer happy or is there a less hackish way of solving this?
And more importantly, why is this happening only with some builds of
my app? (Some other builds are fine)

Any other tips on how to solve and/or avoid this problem?

I have already tried the usual suspects: deleting all profiles, recreating profiles, re-downloading the certificate, etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I noted was that I wasn't using a development provisioning profile for that specific app, I was using the team profile generated by Xcode. I took a shot at creating the development profile, and then it fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, if you're not using iCloud, that your Provisioning Profile on the Apple Developer Page doesn't have iCloud enabled.
If so, disable iCloud and download the new generated profile and try again.
Had a pretty similar problem a few weeks back.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the issue. Read my answer to the problem for more info!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if, while doing a Release build, Xcode decides to use a wildcard provisioning profile.

Even though you go on to choose the correct provisioning profile in Xcode Organizer, when you hit the `Distribute…` button Xcode invokes `xcrun PackageApplication` which embeds the provisioning profile in your app and then resigns it. It also very carefully copies the original *incorrect* entitlements, like App ID Prefix, APN entitlement, gleaned from the wrong provisioning profile, into your new IPA. This will likely fail to install.

I'm not sure why it does this, maybe because not all entitlements come from provisioning profiles.